# How to send analog data of NodeMCU wirelessly to labview for post processing in labview?

Tags: tcp, arduino, labview, nodemcu

I want to send my microphone data wirelessly to labview and then I want to do some post processing over that data like FFT, amplification and stuffs like that.

How should I proceed exactly?

I have researched a lot about this but didn't find any sufficient answer to this. 
I have setup my microcontroller and the microphone module and i am able to get values on the serial monitor.

I have also connected my nodemcu to my AP and thought to use esp8266 as a web-server so that I can send the data to labview but cant possibly do it.

This is my current code:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>    
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

int val=0;        
ESP8266WebServer server(80);    

void setup() {    
  // put your setup code here, to run once:    
  Serial.begin(115200);    
  const char* id = "****";    
  const char* pass = "****";

  WiFi.begin(id,pass);
  while(WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.print("Connected successfully to: ");
  Serial.println(id);
  Serial.print("The IP address is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  server.handleClient();
  int val= analogRead(0);
  Serial.println(val); 
  server.send(200,"text/html",String(val));
}
```

Comment: if labview has a server you can send the data to that server. if labview can only get data from a server, then esp8266 should be a server

Comment: LabVIEW supports TCP/IP and UDP communications and can implement web services so you have plenty of options. It sounds like you need to go back to the LabVIEW help and examples and ask again when you have tried something and you have a more specific question.